# Proof of custom binary strings

Tags: string, binary, proof

Fibonacci is defined recursively for this question as: F~0 = 1 F~1 = 1 F~n = F~n-1 + F~n-2 for n >= 2
So a custom binary string always begins with 1 and never has two consecutive ones. If s = s~Ls~L-1...s~1 is such a string of length L where s~i is in {0,1}, the number represented by s is:
n(s) = Sigma (i = 1 to L) s~i x F~i
Example: n(1000101) = F~7 + F~3 + F~1 = 21 + 3 + 1 = 25

(a) Prove for every L >= 1, if s is a custom binary number of length L, n(s) >= F~L

(b) Prove for every L >= 1, if s is a custom binary number of length L, n(s) < F~L + 1

I've tried to prove with induction with no luck most likely because I'm doing it wrong. I'm not sure how else to prove it for the general case of L > 1.

The '~' is to represent there is a subscript for the variable

Comment: Are you sure you put down the question right? It seems like both of those statements are false to me. For part a, consider the string `10`, with L=2. According to your formula, `n(10) = 1`, which is smaller than `F~2 = 2`. For part b, consider `101`, with length 3. `n(101) = 1xF~1 + 1xF~3 = 1 + 3 = 4`, which is exactly equal to `F~L + 1`

Comment: Forgot to add the example: n(1000101) = F~7 + F~3 + F~1 = 21 + 3 + 1 = 25 so for n(10) = 2 because n(s) = s2 x f2 + s1 x f1 = 2

Comment: Yes, you're right about `n(10)`. Okay, then part a is true, and it's easy to prove (No induction required). However, I'm still not convinced that part b is true for all L. Did I make any mistakes calculating `n(101)`, or in interpreting the answer I got?

Comment: Uh you didn't, but F~L + 1 is greater since the L we talk about is the length of s. So length of s = 3 and n(101) = 4, but F~L+1 = F~4 = 5

Comment: Oh, okay, I misunderstood; I thought the upper bound was `(F~L)+1`, but you meant it to be `F~(L+1)`. Now we're on the same page

Comment: oh yeah sorry should have clarified, but when you say easy to prove without induction you mean by cases or?

Comment: I'm about to start writing up an answer that should clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with A.

I would prove it this way:

> Let `s` be a custom binary string with `L=k` such that `k>=1`. By definition of custom binary strings, we must have `s~k = 1` Therefore `n(s) = F~k + n(s~(k-1)...s(1)) = F~L + n(s~(k-1) ... s(1))`, or the number represented by `s` is equal to `F~L` plus the number represented by the remaining `k-1` digits of `s`. Since we cannot have a string with negative length, we must have that `n(s) >= F~L`

However, if you *need* to prove it inductively, you could do it this way:

> **Base case:** Let `L=1` and `s` be a custom binary string of length 1. We must have `s=1`, by definition. Therefore `n(s) = n(1) = 1xF~1 = F~L`, as required.
>
> **Inductive Hypothesis:** Assume that `n(s) >= F~L` for `L=1,2,...k-1`.
>
> **Inductive case:** Let `L=k`, and let `s` be a custom binary string of length `k`.
>
> If `s` contains only one digit equal to `1`, this is equivalent to the base case and we are done.
>
> If `s` contains more than one digit equal to `1`, let `i` be the index of the second occurrence, and let `t` be the custom binary string represented by the digits `s~i ... s~1`. Then we have that `n(s) = 1xF~k + n(t) = F~L + n(t)`. Since `t` has length `k-i`, by the inductive hypothesis we have `n(s) >= F~L + F~(k-i)>= F~L`, as required.

Okay, B is going to be harder. I'm going to prove it inductively, because I think it's easier.

> **Base case:** Let `L=1` an `s` be a custom binary string of length 1. We must have `s=1`, by definition. Therefore `n(s) = n(1) = 1xF~1 = 1 < 2 = F~2`.
>
> **Inductive Hypothesis:** Assume that n(s) < F~(L+1)`for`L=1,2,...,k-1`.
>
> **Inductive Case:** Let `L=k` and `s` be a custom binary string of length `k`.
>
> If `s` has only one digit equal to `1`, this is equivalent to the base case and we're done. If `s` has more than one digit equal to `1`, then let `i` be the index of the second occurrence, and `t` be the custom binary string represented by the digits `s~i ... 1`.
>
> It is obvious that `n(s) = F~L + n(t)`. By the inductive hypothesis we know that `n(t) < F~(i+1)`. Since custom binary strings cannot have consecutive digits be `1`, we also have that `i <= L-2`, or `i+1 <= L-1`, which means that `F~(i+1) <= F~(L-1)` since the Fibonacci sequence is strictly increasing.
>
> Putting it all together: `n(s) = F~L + n(t) < F~L + F~(i+1) < F~L + F~(L-1) = F~(L+1).`
>
> Therefore `n(s) < F~(L+1)`, as required.